# NSKeyedUnarchiver not working with file made in different app

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedunarchiver

I have two apps that share a drawing canvas, let's call one "child" and the other "parent".

They both encode their own drawings and upload them to Parse. 
When they are sharing the same drawing, it is actually their individual drawings overlaid on one another.

The issue I am having is that they are unable to decode the other person's drawing. They are able to decode their own, and they use the exact same class structure for the drawing canvas and the encoding/decoding process.

These are two separate apps though (since they are built differently otherwise) - is it possible that something about the application ID is encoded into the NSData file?

Comment: As a guess, I'd say that since you're using swift, the package name is encoded into the class name and hence into the streamed archive.  Make sure all your classes are declared with @objc (which will defeat the class name mangling) and see if that works.

Comment: Also, you say that the "class structure" is the same, are you actually using the same classes?  As noted above, the class name gets encoded into the archive, that's how it knows what to recreate.

Comment: Their names and everything inside are identical. I'm trying out your approach now, I'm hoping that'll do the trick.

Comment: It's working in one direction now, so it seems like this is it (knock on wood).

Comment: Not quite sure though why it isn't working in both directions. Thank you!!! I'll update when I get it working in both directions.

Comment: A little bit of retweaking Transport Security (tangentially related) and all is working! The @objc did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess, I'd say that since you're using swift, the package name is encoded into the class name and hence into the streamed archive. Make sure all your classes are declared with @objc (which will defeat the class name mangling) and see if that works.